# Magento2 : Subscription status shows pending in advance reporting

Tags: magento2, admin, reporting

I want to enable advanced reporting in Magento2.

To do this I go to Store->Configuration->General->Advance Reporting and enable it.

**It have been 5 days but still subscription status shows pending.**

Please check screenshot for reference
[image]

I have read this reference link: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html

In Magento Doc It is mention in 5th point as below.

5. Wait overnight, or until after the time of your next scheduled update. Then, check the status of your subscription. If the status is still “pending,” make sure that your installation meets all of the requirements.

But I could not find out what this all requirements are.

Comment: I am not familiar with the advanced reporting but my guess from reading your reference and the [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/advanced-reporting/overview.html) the requirements are those with the checkboxes. Did you verify that all these are met?

Comment: yes @Daniel. I have checked that

Comment: @Jaimin Have you get the solution ? For enabling the Advance Reporting

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [reference link](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html), you will find list of requirements as below.

- **The website must run on a public web server.** : You must have your website on a public domain, it will not work with local machine setup.
- **The domain must have a valid security (SSL) certificate.** : Your website must have installed and configured a valid SSL.
- **Magento must have been installed or upgraded successfully without
  error.** : Simply means, there should not be any error with your Magento instance.
- **In the Magento configuration, the Base URL (Secure) setting for the
  store view must point to the secure URL. For example
  https://yourdomain.com.** : You will require to setup your secure URL with `https` at `Stores > Configurations > General > Web > Base URLs (Secure)`
- **In the Magento configuration, Use Secure URLs on Storefront, and Use
  Secure URLs in Admin must be set to “Yes.”** : You must have to use secure URL on your storefront too. Set `Stores > Configurations > General > Web > Base URLs (Secure) > Use Secure URLs on Storefront` and `Use Secure URLs in Admin` to `Yes`
- **Make sure that Magento crontab is created and cron jobs are running
  on the installed server.** : You must have cronjobs working on your magento instance.

Once you have setup everything as described above, Go to `System > Extensions > Integrations`

Go to **Magento Analytics user** and click `Reauthorize`.
In the next modal, Click on `Reauthorize` button.
This will give you below keys:

1. Consumer Key
2. Consumer Secret
3. Access Token
4. Access Token Secret

You can save these keys for future reference. Click on `Done`.

Now, you have to wait for the next cron run for scheduled update (may take 24 hours). Once done successfully, you will be able to see your status as `Enabled`
[image]

Comment: As an alternative you can go for Advanced Reporting extension, which would essentially address these issues[https://rb.gy/6y1vry]